# At what point is an app name taken? iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone

I am confused as to when an app name is taken.  Today I added a new app in iTunes Connect using the + sign.  I first tried to use Facebook as a name.  It gave an error: taken..., fine. I then changed to my desired name and "created the app".  Will others now be unable to use my name?  Or will they get the same error as when I used Name: Facebook ?  I am wondering because I found this text on a StackOverflow question :

> The name you select for your app is perhaps one of the most important
>   aspects to marketing your app and can distinguish your app on the App
>   Store. If you submit an app name which is already in use within the
>   same geography in which your app is sold, you will be prompted to
>   enter another name.

Since you select a geography at a later stage(submission) is appears this is the point where you reserve the name.

I guess I could find out by creating a dummy record and then ask another developer to try and create the same record.  But if anyone of you guys know, it would be helpful.  I am sure other are wondering the same as well. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App names are registered when you create an app in Itunes Connect. Weather you 've posted the app to appstore or not. This name is registered with you. And no one can choose that name once the name is registered in itunes connect. So don't worry, others will get the same error when they choose this name what you've selected.

Comment: Woho... 3 letter word with a meaning - feeling unbelievably lucky !